# Most Videos Will Not Play in Ubuntu 20.04 (or anything later than 16.04)

Tags: vlc, 20.04

I have been using Ubuntu 16.04 with absolutely no issues, but as the End of Life for 16.04 approaches I have been getting nervous. I tried to switch to 18.04 in the past (fresh install on several machines), but videos would not play. I went back to 16.04 (fresh install on several machines), and everything was fine.

I just installed 20.04 to see if videos would play, but unfortunately most videos do not play.

Of course I installed ubuntu restricted extras, and vlc. I tried turning hardware acceleration on and off in vlc, and changing the video output to each different setting, and all of which had no effect. The videos would play the first frame, and then turn off. Again, some videos will play in vlc (480p mkv), but not 720p or 1080p. Here's what's strange though; some of the videos that will not play in vlc will play in the video player that came with ubuntu.

I've searched forums, and there's nothing that addresses this issue; why everything works in 16.04, but not in anything later.

I'm going to eventually have to drop 16.04 on all 4 of my machines, as well as my dad's box, but if I can't get videos to play, at least without having to mess around between video players there's no way I can continue to use 20.04 or 18.04 for that matter. My dad is going to have to be put back to windows....eww.

Comment: Start a video from commandline using vlc. If there is something that causes an error it will be reported in the command line session. We need that info. Otherwise you might find something in one of the logs in /var/log/.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, but first I would like to share more details regarding my issue:

I was attempting to play video files saved on my Western Digital My Book Live Duo Network Attached Storage drive. In order to access these files I would open up the file explorer (was Nautilus in 16.04, and now it's just called Files in 20.04) and mount a network drive (and mark it as a favourite). Selecting the 'Network' using Nautilus, or '+ Other Locations' in Files would bring up a list of the network drives. I've always had two options: One was "MYBOOKLIVEDUO" and the other was 'MyBookLiveDuo'. Both had the same contents, and I never understood why there was two options for the same drive, and I did not question it either. I would always select the all caps version.

The all caps version MYBOOKLIVEDUO was where the video files were located that I couldn't get to play in vlc (some worked, some did not). If I copied the files to the internal drive they would all play locally.

I tried accessing the files with the MyBookLiveDuo version, and the files would play perfectly right off the network drive.

I looked into this further, and I found that the file paths that were located using MYBOOKLIVEDUO begin with smb. The file paths that were located using MyBookLiveDuo begin with afp.

I guess this is an issue for vlc not liking some files through smb.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, but I updated from 18.04 LTS (where I had no trouble with video reproduction). This is affecting also the ability to run programs like Kdenlive or Blender. I reinstalled ffmpeg but anything changed.